# Search For All Locations In Active Dirrectory Via LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm working in PL/SQL and searching LDAP ( with A.D defining the schema) for all locations. Right now I can apply a simple search and find all users. Each user has the address information via the following properties:

```
'physicalDeliveryOfficeName';
'streetAddress';
'l';--city
'st';--state
'postalCode';--zip code
```

However, I would like to search for all the locations separate from the search done for people. Is it possible to search Active directory to just find the locations(with out looking up each person) ? If so what would the search filter look like ? I tried objectClass=Physical-Location,DC=example,DC=com and didn't find any locations (beyond the schema) . I'm not sure if that's because there's a security issue, or its not possible to look up locations in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have listed are attributes in AD. You can return attributes in searches and search for specific values but you'll always return the objects the attributes are attached to (in this case users).  You're a little light on the details of how you're searching so I'll take a stab.

You can load just the location attributes you're looking for, be it State, City, etc.

```
var domain = "mydomain.com";
var dn = "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com";

var ldapSearchFilter = "(objectClass=user)";
var connection = new LdapConnection(domain);
var attributeList = new string[] { "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "l", "st"};

try
{
    var searchRequest = 
            new SearchRequest(dn, ldapSearchFilter,
                              SearchScope.OneLevel,
                              attributeList);

var searchResponse = 
            (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

var locationList = (from SearchResultEntry entry in searchResponse.Entries 
                    select entry.Attributes["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0].ToString())
                    .Distinct().ToList();

catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle errors
}
```

One thing to keep in mind with this example.  If the attributes aren't populated in AD, the WriteLine will throw an error when trying to read the attribute.  If you are using some other search type (DirectorySearcher maybe) you should still be able to load just the attributes you want to get back.

Comment: But what I'm asking is will that pull a distinct list of all locations ? Is there a way to just search for locations. I think the answer is no, but I don't know that for sure..

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure what you mean by location but no, you can't do a search just for locations in the sense I believe you mean.  However, you could use linq to get the distinct values from this list.  Again remember, if one of the user's has a value that isn't populated it will throw an exception.  See the edited code above.

Comment: The code I actually wrote is all in pl/sql (so it can run on the sever)  but is tied to my companies implementation so I didn't post it.. I thought it wasn't possible to just pull a location list, I just wanted to get confirmation that I wasn't missing something.  I did pull out distinct lists from the duplicates..